# SQL query for text analysis

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I want a SQL query which I have to apply in a text column containing multiple sentences in English. Now suppose I want to retrieve all the data or rows which contains the word 'hanging' and 'issue' and also which contains just 'hanging' word.

1. "my phone is hanging"
2. "my phone has hanging issue"
3. "my mobile has hanging issue."

Now if I use `like (%hanging%) AND like (%issue%)` then I will get the result as no.2 and no.3 but no.1 will be missed.

So I want a query which can retrieve all the 3 sentences.

Comment: This is not how SO works, you have to post some of code efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: 1. "my phone is hanging"  2. "my phone has hanging issue" 3."my mobile has hanging issue."     now if I use  like (%hanging%) AND like ( %issue%)    then I will get the result as no 2. and no.3 but no.1 will be missed. so i want a query which can retrieve all the 3 sentences.

Comment: instead of using AND you can use OR  -> (%hanging%) OR like ( %issue%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly need to "OR" the words you want to query.

1) my phone is hanging  => `"%hanging%"` matches

2) my phone has hanging issue => `"%hanging%" and "%issue%"` matches

3) my mobile has hanging issue. => `"%hanging%" and "%issue%"` matches

so, as you're asking for both "hanging" and "issue", its clear why only 2 and 3 match - you need to OR them.

So, the solution will be:

`like ('%hanging%') OR like ('%issue%')`

Not sure if that solves your problem, because now also following sentence would match:

4) my mobile phone has no issue

You need to decide if that is OK for you - don't know details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just filter "hanging", you will always get "hanging" **or** "hanging with issues" **or** "hanging without issues". In short, you don't have to filter for issues anywhere because all you want to make sure you have in a statement is "hanging".

`select * from table where column like (%hanging%)`